# Very strange behaviour of fgets() with Xcode 6

Tags: c, xcode, fgets

I've very strange behaviour with the next lines of code:

```
int running = TRUE;
char *input = (char*)calloc(256, sizeof(char));

while(running) {
    printf("Enter command: ");
    fgets(input, MAXINPUT, stdin);
    processInput(input);
}
```

When I enter a text manually in XCode console, `input` which passed to `processInput` function is filled with data which I entered, but when I paste a line of text instead of typing it manually it passed only '\n' char to `processInput`. Even If I first type this line manually and then copy past it doesn't work. The most strange thing that it worked for me, but while I make changing in my program I suddenly realized that it stopped to work, and I haven't done changes relevant to this part of code.

What's wrong with it?
Thank you.

Comment: Try pasting that same line into a text editor, and see if it gets pasted on a new line (i.e. to see if the first character of the pasted line is `'\n'`).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, no it left on the same line

Comment: `256 >= MAXINPUT` ?  `input != NULL`?

Comment: @chux, no. I think it was a bug. I commented processInput(input) line and added code printf("%s",input) below. It took for XCode a while to recompile and it started to print value of input. After that I uncommented processInput(input) and deleted printf... and it began to work. I tried before this to perform clean and of course build but it didn't help until I've changed a code.

Comment: No?  Then suggest allocating `char *input = calloc(MAXINPUT, sizeof(char)); if (input == NULL) Handle_OOM()` to get enough memory and insure it is valid.

Comment: @chux, `if (input == NULL) Handle_OOM()` not really understand this line of code

Comment: If `calloc()` returns `NULL`, them code must handle the out-of-memory (OOM) condition.

Comment: ok, this behaviour returns after a while. Definitely I do something wrong but can't understand what? I've changed my code to the following:   `while(running) {
        printf("Enter command: ");
        fgets(input, MAXINPUT, stdin);
        processInput(input);
        free(input);
        input = (char*)calloc(MAXINPUT+1, sizeof(char));
        if (!input) {
            printf("memory");
        }
    }` Don't sure that it's right way.

Comment: I tried to replace fgets with `while ((c=getchar()!='\n')) {
            *(input + i) = c;
        }` and again, it worked once and then `c` get strange input `\x01`